# What is "H" in opcodes (very confused)

Tags: opcode

In my computer organization class, we're learning opcodes, and i understand most of the opcodes, and the concepts of them, but seriously, theres no legend for what "H" is for example..

```
iadd

iadd1:mar=sp=sp-1;rd
iadd2: H =tos..
```

whats H??

x'D thanks!

Comment: What language of assembly is it?

Comment: my colleague just told me its IJVM : sorry :/

Comment: then tag the question with the architecture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

H is a register name, not an opcode.

> Hold (H)
>
> This register holds data that is to be supplied to the left (A) input of the arithmetic logic unit. This is the only register that can perform this function.

http://dsearls.org/courses/C391OrgSys/SimHelp/HTML/IJVM_Register_Set.htm

Comment: you are a sir. thanks ^_^ confirmed my suspicions, but i'm still failing this test :')